# Uninstall SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

how do I uninstall SQL Server 2008 manually? Add/remove programs does not uninstall everything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall SQL all the way, use the uninstaller to remove the instance and services. Then delete the install directories.

Or, check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412.aspx) from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

it is not very easy to [remove SQL Server 2008](http://www.mightyuninstaller.com/Uninstall-REAL-SQL-Server-2008-102717.html) manually. Removing it via Add/Remove Programs is just enough. Before you uninstall an instance of SQL Server 2008, you have to 
1. Back up your data. 
2.Delete the local security groups.
3.Save or rename Reporting Services folders.
4.Delete the Reporting Services virtual directories and the the ReportServer application pool.
5.Stop all SQL Server services. 
6.Use an account that has the appropriate permissions.

After you finish the steps above, 
Step 1. uninstall SQL Server 2008 via Control Panel. 
Step 2. On the Component Selection - Uninstall page, select a server or a shared component that you want to remove.
Click the Report button to view the list of SQL Server components and features that are installed. The report includes version information, edition information, update level information, and language information for each installed component and feature.
Step 3. Click Next.
Step 4. On the Confirmation - Uninstall page, review the list of components and features that will be removed, and then click Next. The Setup Progress page will display the status of the Setup program.
Step 5. On the Completing Setup page, click Finish to exit the Installation Wizard.
Step 6. Repeat steps 2 to 5 until all SQL Server 2008 components have been removed.
Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955499